# How can I post videos and photos on instagram using python without selenium?

Tags: python, automation, instagram, instagram-api

I want to be able to post photos and videos with descriptions from python and no library on the internet works, I tried instagrapi, instapy_cli, instabot and nothing. None of them work. When I use the code to make the post instagram detects suspicious activity and forces me to change password.

I tried use instagrapi, instabot and instapy_cli.